# Passing data to a top level parent from low level child components in a nested Vue.js component organization?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I understand that the Vue.js architecture requires you to pass data to children using props and use events to do it the other way around. But this gets really messy when there are nested children. I mean how am I supposed to neatly transfer data from a low-level child all the way to its highest parent. Right now, I have to emit an event in the child, and handle it in the immediate parent which then has to emit another which eventually gets handled in the top-level parent.

What's the standard way to do this?

Should I use vuex or something? Isn't there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Yes, use Vuex.  There are other ways but none better, and it's very simple.

Comment: if it's a simple situation and a few interaction between grandparent component and some of its grandchildren you could use dependency injection else use vuex or observable based store

Comment: @Dan Ha, alright. Thanks.